# start directory of a file explorer Intent for Android

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, file-manager

What is the correct way to start a File Explorer by Intent in a specified directory?

Following code snippet  works fine, except that it starts in the wrong directory.

The desired starting point would be at "selectedUri"

```
 val selectedUri = Uri.parse(externalStorage.toString() + "DCIM/Camera/")
 val intent= Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply{
         addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
         type = "image/*"
         addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to set the intent data

```
val selectedUri = Uri.parse(externalStorage.toString() + "DCIM/Camera/")
val intent= Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply{
         addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
         data = selectedUri
         type = "image/*"
         addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
 }
```

Comment: Yes I agree with you, however it does not work on my Samsung XCover